# MATLAB compass north

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a rather simple question regarding MATLAB compass plot.

Whenever I try to plot direction using compass plot in MATLAB the 90 degree pointer always points north. Is this because the north reference in MATLAB is 90 degrees? How can I change it so the north reference is 0 degrees? This is because I'm working with windspeed vectors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you generate the compass figure, try :

```
az = 90; % azimuth i.e. rotate around z-axis horizontally by 90 degrees
el = -90; % elevation negative, effectively looking beneath plot
view(az, el);
```

You can also use `camroll` to do this:

```
camroll(90)
```

this actually rotates the camera looking at the plot clockwise, not the plot itself. So if you want to rotate the plot 90 degrees counter-clockwise, you will need to rotate the camera 90 degrees clockwise...

Comment: my oh my... You have no idea how much time I spent trying to do this... BIGGEST thank