# Rotating MATLAB's polar plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

I am trying to use the MATLAB command `polar`, and it seems to start with 0 degrees on the right hand side, with angles increasing in a counter-clockwise direction.

What I would like to do however, it change this, so that the polar co-ordinate system starts with 0-degrees as 'North', and the angles increase in a clockwise direction.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

EDIT: I want MATLAB to *show* a polar plot, where 0 starts at North, and angles are increasing in a clockwise fashion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB compass north](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116586/matlab-compass-north)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your polar plot as usual, then call `view(90, -90)`. This changes the viewpoint without changing anything else about the plot.

Comment: That rotates it but does not flip the counterclockwise orientation. Is there a simple way to flip the left-right orientation? That would be a simpler answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Find `polar.m` and make a copy (I called mine mypolar.m, I found it by running polar to cause an error and clicking the link for the line number in the error message.) Edit the following lines:

Lines 133-134:

```
    % plot spokes
    th = (1 : 6) * 2 * pi / 12;
    cst = sin(th);
    snt = cos(th);
    cs = [-cst; cst];
    sn = [-snt; snt];
```

Lines 180-181:

```
    % transform data to Cartesian coordinates.
    xx = rho .* sin(theta);
    yy = rho .* cos(theta);
```

You swap sin and cos twice. I think this gets everything...

Comment: Im sorry, perhaps I was not clear. I know how to compensate for different co-ordinate systems. :-) What I want is to change the _actual_ underlying polar plot MATLAB uses. Even if I do what you do, MATLAB doesnt show what I want.

Comment: Russ, there is no code to provide. If you simply do polar(theta,rho), you get a plot, where 0 is on the RHS, and angles increase in a counter-clockwise direction. I dont want this. I want the polar system to have 0 start at North, and angles to increase in the clockwise direction.

Comment: Russ, I am accepting the other answer only because it is a lot simpler, but thanks again for your post, I did learn from you as well. :-)